# Prevent Adding everytime i change the Drop Down Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm Stuck in a situation where the Marker on every Change on Dropdown List of radius is Adding Marker everytime. . .Do I need to SetMap Null every Change of Dropdown list so the Marker Doesn't become populated with Identical Marker??

Or other approach or Changes that i need to do in my Set of Codes

```
var Rad = 0;
var customerlocationID = 0;

var geocoder, infoBubble, geocode;
var map;
var selectedMarker;
var ID;
//var mgr;
$("#ddlRadius").live("change", function () {
    var selectValue = "";
    selectValue = $("#ddlRadius option:selected").val();

    if (selectValue == "77") {
        Rad = 5;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    }
    else if (selectValue == "78") {
        Rad = 10;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    }
    else if (selectValue == "79") {
        Rad = 25;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    }
    else if (selectValue == "80") {
        Rad = 50;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    }
    else if (selectValue == "81") {
        Rad = 100;
        codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
    }
});



function initialize() {
    var minZoomLevel = 4;
    var zooms = 7;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocode = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    // Used to Set the Center of the Maps on the Logged User
    $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadAddress', function Geocoding(address) {
        $.each(address, function () {
            customerlocationID = this["ID"];
            var currValAddress = this["AddressLine1"];
            var Latitude = this["Latitude"];
            var Longitude = this["Longitude"];
            var LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);
            var addresse = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: LatLang,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), addresse);


            // Bounds for North America
            var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
              new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
              new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90));

            // Listen for the dragend event
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
                if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;
                // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

                var c = map.getCenter(),
              x = c.lng(),
              y = c.lat(),
              maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
              maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
              minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
              minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

                if (x < minX) x = minX;
                if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
                if (y < minY) y = minY;
                if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
            });

            // Limit the zoom level
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
                if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
            });
        });
    });
    codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad);
}



var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
function codeAddress(customerlocationID, Rad) {
    infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        map: map,
        shadowStyle: 0,
        padding: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
        arrowSize: 15,
        maxWidth: 300,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#ccc',
        arrowPosition: 50,
        arrowStyle: 0
    });
    $.getJSON('/Dashboard/LoadWorkerList1' + '?customerLocationID=' + customerlocationID + '&radius=' + Rad, function Geocode(addresses) {
        $.each(addresses, function () {
            var currVal = this["AddressLine1"];
            var Name = this["Name"];
            var Gender = this["Gender"];
            var Bdate = this["Birthdate"];
            ID = this["Worker_ID"];
            var distance = this["Distance"];
            var workerDetailIDDD = this["Worker_ID"];
            var Latitude = this["Latitude"];
            var Longitude = this["Longitude"];
            var LatLang = new google.maps.LatLng(Latitude, Longitude);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                icon: '/Content/images/male.png',
                position: LatLang,
                title: currVal
            })

            var link = $('<a href="#">' + currVal + '</a>').data('location', LatLang);
            $('#places').append($('<li id=\'List\' class=\'List\'>').append(link));
            link.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                google.maps.event.trigger(addresses[0], "click");
                if (selectedMarker) {
                    selectedMarker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
                }
                marker.setIcon('/Content/images/maleclicked.png');
                selectedMarker = marker;
                infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br> Distance: " + distance + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Dashboard/WorkerMapDetail?workerId=' + workerDetailIDDD + '" onclick="window.open(this.href,height=850,width=1200);return false""><span style="font-size: 12px !important">View Profile</span></a></center>');
                infoBubble.open(map, marker);
            });


            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function () {
                $('#places li').each(function () {
                    var inside = (map.getBounds().contains($(this).find('a').data('location'))) ? '' : 'none';
                    $(this).css('display', inside);
                });
            });

            // Listen for user click on map to close any open info bubbles
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function () {
                infoBubble.close();
                marker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dragstart", function () {
                infoBubble.close();
                marker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                return function () {
                    if (selectedMarker) {
                        selectedMarker.setIcon('/Content/images/male.png');
                    }


                    marker.setIcon('/Content/images/maleclicked.png');
                    selectedMarker = marker;
                    infoBubble.removeTab(0);
                    infoBubble.addTab(Name, "Name: " + Name + "<br> Address: " + currVal + "<br> Gender: " + Gender + "<br> Birthdate: " + Bdate + "<br> Distance: " + distance + "<br><br>" + '<center><a href="/Dashboard/WorkerMapDetail?workerId=' + workerDetailIDDD + '" onclick="window.open(this.href,height=850,width=1200);return false""><span style="font-size: 12px !important">View Profile</span></a></center>');
                    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
                }

            })(marker, currVal));
            addresses.push(marker);

        })


        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'bounds_changed');


    })

}


window.onload = function () {
    initialize();
}
```

Comment: It seems that for each radius change you retrieve new set of markers. You have to set markers from previous set not just setMap(null) but also set marker to null to delete it completely. Otherwise memory will be spent. Similar issue with event listeners.

Comment: @AntoJurković can you help me on how should i use it in my code?

Comment: What for is this line `addresses.push(marker);`?

Comment: @AntoJurković sorry i forgot to remove that line. . does nothing. .

Comment: @AntoJurković i hope you can help me with this 1

Comment: Basic idea is: define global array for markers: `var markers = [];`. In `codeAddress()` function clean markers from that array at the beginning: `if (markers.length) { for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) { markers[i].setMap(null); markers[i] = null; } markers.length = 0; }`. And when a marker is created: `markers.push(marker);`. If you want also to clean event handlers that you will have to track some more information in similar way. You can try just with markers for the beginning.

Comment: @AntoJurković will it remove all the marker before i get the other markers when i change the Dropdown Value?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48348/discussion-between-ren-tao-and-anto-jurkovic)